# Ubuntu 14.04 QtCreator Qt5 examples missing

Tags: permissions, 14.04, documentation, qt-creator, qt5

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I removed the official qtcreator in order to install the modified version from the software center because I'd like to try the SDK.

Fortunately, the docs are now included in the official installation. Unfortunately, there is still something missing: the official examples. Luckily I had my old and official installation still on my harddrive and then, after some tries, I copied the examples to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples` and change the permission. Then QtCreator detected examples and I was able to select them from the examples section.

But there are still two problems remaining:

**Firstly**, I am not able to find all examples e.g the network examples (like the fortuneclient) are still missing. For the sake of testing I change the permission of the example folder to `777`. Therefore permission shouldn't be a problem.

**Secondly**, some helping documents to the examples are missing. Therefore I get a normal editor and a blank right part after clicking on an example.

Comment: O.K. this help but installed QT Creator main help page is still missing.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 17.04, I also had to install `qt5-default`, which is a "kit" needed to even open the basic examples.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get the Qt5.2 examples available in Qt Creator/Ubuntu SDK, you basically need two extra packages, open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> an type:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples qtbase5-doc-html
```

Restart Qt Creator to get:

[image]

Comment: I had to install a few more packages before examples and qtcreator help were working. In particular qtcreator-doc. Use 'apt-cache search qt |grep -E "doc|demo|tut|examp"' to see what you might wish to install. Some packages I have installed: 'dpkg-query -l |awk '{print $2}' |grep qt |grep -E "doc|demo|tut|examp" |fmt'
qt4-demos qt4-doc qt4-doc-html qt5-doc qt5-doc-html
qtbase5-doc qtbase5-doc-html qtbase5-examples qtcreator-doc

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 this doesn't work at all. The Qt5 examples can apparently not be loaded from a read-only location (`qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES"`).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Sylvain's answer so my answer here is to back it up and expand as per gaoithe's comments.

In my case running Qt Creator 3.0.1 based on Qt 5.2.1. (on Ubuntu 14.04)

I had `qtbase5-examples qtbase5-doc-html` already installed, but was still missing network and multimedia examples (and others evidently, but these were the ones I cared about).

After installing the following additional packages:

```
qt4-demos qt4-doc qt4-doc-html qt5-doc qt5-doc-html
```

Now I have a shed load of examples that I didn't know were missing.

Thanks

Comment: OP asked for qt5 examples, those are are using the Qt4 API. But it's always good to have them installed. +1

Comment: In my case I think the absence of some of the Qt5 examples was resolved by installing the `qt5-doc qt-5-doc-html` packages in particular.  I did have some examples in the Qt5 directory that were not showing until these packages were installed.

Comment: For the docs the package qt5-doc is important.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the QtCreator examples and API docs missing,
This is my way to solve this problem, should apply to almost every Ubuntu release.

For QtCreator and Examples and API Docs:

```bsh
sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-examples | grep qt | grep example | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs `

sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-doc | grep "Qt 5 " | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`

sudo apt-get install build-essential qtcreator qt5-default
```

If something is also missing, then:

```bsh
sudo apt install `apt-cache search qt | grep 5- | grep ^qt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs `
```

Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and also suffering this "examples not showing" issue. Also, when opening an existing qt-based project, it complains "kits is not OK to use".

And if I do `sudo qtcreator`, these problems disappear.

Finally, by manually choosing qmake to select the proper qt version it is solved.

i.e. in **Menu > Settings > Kits > Kits > Qt Version**, if it is *None*, manage it, choosing `/usr/bin/qmake`, then save.

Comment: Using `sudo` other than for testing purposes is a _really bad_ advice for running an application like `qtcreator`. PLEASE don't do that. The very last point, however, was spot on. I've even had that with the version installed from the "web installer" before.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Mint 18.1 using Qt Creator 3.5.1 based on Qt 5.5.1, I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples qtbase5-doc-html qt4-demos qt4-doc qt4-doc-html qt5-doc qt5-doc-html
```

Then I got a substantial number of Examples shown in the Welcome Screen.

Comment: That finally fixed it for me.

Comment: Well you seem to be installing Qt4 examples, so could you check whether that substantial number of examples is even related to Qt5?! Or whether any of the Qt5 examples show up? For me on Ubuntu 20.04 none show up. Only if I happen to start `qtcreator` privileged. The reason seems to be that the folder `qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES"` is read-only.

Comment: Yup, thank you, this worked for me.