# Qt creator Learning tutorial for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, qt-creator

I am a new user for Ubuntu and qt creator, I want to learn Qt program with examples.

Where could I find documentation about Qt Creator?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of examples and tutorials are available in Qt  Creator itself, just click on the Welcome icon on the left toolbar and select "Demos and Examples":

[image]

**Note**: Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/451892/32239) to get Qt Creator Qt5 examples on 14.04